# add workloads to an existing visual studio local cache(layout)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I have a existing local cache for visual studio 2019 for certain workload.
I need to add another workload {Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node} along with its offline layout cache
which arguments should I use

Things i Tried.

> vs_community.exe --layout  D:\Software\Compiler\vslayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node --IncludeRecommended

Scanned through microsoft docs. but shows how to install but not update local cache

Answer (score 0):

Found something, this may work..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019